# How to make the specified command run in vim?

Tags: shell, vim

I know how to make shell command run in vim,in command mode,type

```
:!shell_command
```

Now, I have a command in line 16 of a file open in Vim.

```
cp /home/debian/Downloads/rar/rar /usr/local/bin
```

[image: screenshot]

How can I run this command in vim, without typing all of it?

When I hit `:!` to open up the ex command line and then use `<C-r>"`, I get this:

```
ls /tmp^m
```

[image: screenshot]

I have to erase `^m` with the backspace key, and press the enter key, is that right?
can i not to let ^M  to be shown ?

Comment: are you asking how to run the command on the line of your cursor?

Comment: If a `^M` shows up after the yank then yes your should erase it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer:

```
:exec '!'.getline('.')
```

Answer (score 2):

To run the command on the line your cursor is on you can yank the line into you clipboard. Type `:!` to open up the ex command line and then use `<C-r>"` to paste the command onto the command line.

So with the cursor on the line type and hit enter.

```
yy:!<C-r>"
```

Take a look at `:h <c-r>`.

```
CTRL-R {0-9a-z"%#:-=.}                  *c_CTRL-R* *c_<C-R>*
        Insert the contents of a numbered or named register.  Between
        typing CTRL-R and the second character '"' will be displayed
        to indicate that you are expected to enter the name of a
        register.
        The text is inserted as if you typed it, but mappings and
        abbreviations are not used.  Command-line completion through
        'wildchar' is not triggered though.  And characters that end
        the command line are inserted literally (<Esc>, <CR>, <NL>,
        <C-C>).  A <BS> or CTRL-W could still end the command line
        though, and remaining characters will then be interpreted in
        another mode, which might not be what you intended.
        Special registers
```

Comment: i have to erase ^m with bachspace key,and press enter key ,is that right?

Comment: If a `^M` shows up after the yank then yes you should erase it

Comment: @it_is_a_literature yes you need to press the backspace key and then press the enter key. Is there something you don't get?

Comment: can i make it more simple,more convenient? not to let ^M to be shown,so that i can just press enter key.

Comment: @it_is_a_literature If you didn't already know, `^M` is a newline character used in Vim. For more information see `:h digraph-table`. If it bothers you, only select the words, and not the whole line.

Comment: replace `yy` with `y$` to not copy the newline, and you shouldn't have to delete the `^M`.

Comment: the only problem with `y$` is that it grabs from the cursor location to the end of the line. So you might need to do `0y$` or `^y$` to grab the whole command.